# Nested Div Height Won't Change

Tags: html, height

Alright. First of all, I am very new to CSS and HTML. I have been working on this project and learning as I go. With that being said, if you could explain your answers a little that would help me out a lot!

Anyway. Long story short, I am creating a form and trying to lay it out with div's displayed as a table (I know how to use HTML tables, I chose to use div's so I can style it better with CSS).

Basically, I have a main div that is displayed as a table and has the height set to 100%. then I have nested div's that are displayed as table rows (5 total), and additional nested div's that are displayed as table cells.

The problem I have is that when I set the height of either the rows or cells, they don't change...AT ALL! Keep in mind, I am using percentages not px or em.

I am trying to get rows 1 and 5 to be at 5% of the 100% from the main div, and 2 - 4 to be at 30% out of the 100% from the main div. I assumed that this would equal 100% and cause the rows to match the 100% height of the main div. It's obviously not working so I assume my logic is entirely wrong.

I have searched for a solution and have not found one, which is why I am here.

Here is an idea of what I am doing:

```
#MainDivTable
{
    display: table;
    height: 100%
    width: 100%;
}

#DivCol1Row2
{
    height: 30%;
}

#DivCol1Row3
{
    height: 30%;
}

#DivCol1Row4
{
    height: 30%;
}

#DivCol1Row5
{
    height: 5%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that percentage heights are always percentages of *something*
i.e. when you specify mainTable height as 100%, it has to be 100% of something, which generally is the parent's height.

First you need to set the height of the parent as a fixed value or else you can propogate percentage heights upward the layout until you reach the root element.

In your case, I think,

```
    html, body { height:100%;}
```

should do the trick.